# How to get the records using dynamic soql for the date field which is equal to NULL

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-soql

I have a requirement where the user should be able to include the records where the due date is not populated when i uncheck the checkbox field in the vf page.In my case that date field is named as Due_Date__c.

I have written the follwing dynamic soql code.But it is not fetching the records where the due date is not populated.

```
public class PrivateEquityReport
{
   ApexPages.StandardSetController regionStandardSetController{get;set;}
   private Id privateRecordTypeId = Fund_Activity__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(' Amendment').getRecordTypeId();
   public AI_PrivateEquityWeeklyTrackingReport()
   String baseQuery = 'SELECT Id,Due_Date__c,Fund__r.Name,Company__r.Name,Subject__c,Comments__c,Date_Received__c,Business_Review__c,Attorney_Review__c FROM Fund__c WHERE Team__c=\'Equity\' AND RecordTypeId =:privateRecordTypeId';

   public PrivateEquityReport()
  {
    regionStandardSetController=new ApexPages.StandardSetController(new  list<Fund__c>());
    String dueDateCheck=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('DueDateCheck');
    if(dueDateCheck=='true')
      isDueDate=true; 
   else
      isDueDate=false;
  }

public String  getReportText()
{
    String checkQuery = baseQuery;

     String reportFromDateVar = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('dFromDate');
     Date fromDateVar = null;
    if(reportFromDateVar != null)
    fromDateVar = Date.valueOf(reportFromDateVar);
    System.debug('*****From Date***'+fromDateVar );

     String reportToDateVar = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('dToDate');
     Date toDateVar = null;
    if(reportToDateVar != null)
    toDateVar = Date.valueOf(reportToDateVar );
     System.debug('*****To Date***'+toDateVar );

     if((fromDateVar!= null)&&(toDateVar!=null)&&(!isDueDate))
    {
      checkQuery =checkQuery +' '+'and (Due_Date__c>=:fromDateVar AND Due_Date__c<= :toDateVar)';
      checkQuery =checkQuery +' '+'and Due_Date__c=NULL';
      system.debug('************3'+checkQuery);
    }

    regionStandardSetController=new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(checkQuery));
    activityRecords= regionStandardSetController.getRecords();
     displayPrivateEquity ='<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>' + displayPrivateEquity ;                
     displayPrivateEquity = prepareReportSinglePagePrivateEquity(activityRecords,displayPrivateEquity );
     return  displayPrivateEquity; 
}
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me what 'system.debug('************3'+checkQuery);' line prints in log?

Comment: @Saumya Ranjan Satapathy I have updated the code please check with it....i need a records within the range of from and to date that i am providing in the vf page along with the records where due_date which does not have value in that....

Comment: That system debug will give this 18:14:37:069 USER_DEBUG [124]|DEBUG|************3SELECT Id,Due_Date__c,Fund__r.Name,Company__r.Name,Subject__c,Comments__c,Date_Received__c,Business_Review__c,Attorney_Review__c FROM Fund__c WHERE Team__c='Equity' AND RecordTypeId =:privateRecordTypeId and (Due_Date__c>=:fromDateVar AND Due_Date__c<= :toDateVar) and Due_Date__c=NULL and (Date_Received__c>=:receivefromDateVar AND Date_Received__c<= :receivetoDateVar ) AND Executed__c=:executedCheck

Comment: how your query string is not ending with 'and Due_Date__c=NULL'??  or are you using ************3 in other places? @Learner_sfdc

Comment: from your query string it looks like an invalid condition, **(Due_Date__c>=:fromDateVar AND Due_Date__c<= :toDateVar) and Due_Date__c=NULL'**. You will not get value that is less than null **AND** greater than null **AND** equal to null. This criteria will never satishfy. Please revisit your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query:

```
(Due_Date__c>=:fromDateVar AND Due_Date__c <= :toDateVar) and Due_Date__c=NULL
```

This criteria will never satisfy.

For Example, if fromDateVar==null and toDateVar==null,
then the query is expecting a Due_Date__c that is less than null AND greater than null AND equal to null. Please revisit your query.

Comment: Ranjan To get both the criteria to work.... what query i need to use.please help

Comment: May b like (   
(Due_Date__c>=:fromDateVar AND Due_Date__c <= :toDateVar) OR Due_Date__c=NULL  )

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing the `checkQuery` variable as below:

```
checkQuery =checkQuery +' '+'and Due_Date__c = NULL';
```

**Note:**

- You don't need exact type variable for `NULL` checks, NULL is a NULL irrespective of whatever data type your want to check

Comment: Hi karthik,Thanks for the reply...No it is also not working....  The records are there with due_date__c with no data in that...Those are not fetching....it is showing blank list...

Comment: Then I think before the `AND` you have the `baseQuery` with some other criteria which is filtering it

Comment: No i havent given other criteria...i have commented all those...still it is not fetching any records

Comment: Can you paste the final SOQL query ? I will try debugging it from my end

Comment: 12:36:24:019 USER_DEBUG [119]|DEBUG|************3SELECT Id,Due_Date__c,Fund__r.Name,Company__r.Name,Subject__c,Comments__c,Date_Received__c,Business_Review__c,Attorney_Review__c FROM Fund__c WHERE Team__c='Equity' AND RecordTypeId =:privateRecordTypeId and Due_Date__c=NULL

Comment: Are you able to view records with Due_Date__c `NULL` when you ran the query `SELECT Id,Due_Date__c,Fund__r.Name,Company__r.Name,Subject__c,Comments__c,Date_Received__c,Bu‌​siness_Review__c,Attorney_Review__c FROM Fund__c WHERE Team__c='Equity' AND RecordTypeId =:privateRecordTypeId` ?

Comment: No records it is fetching....its 0.

Comment: Problem is with the Previous conditions and not will `Due_Date__c = NULL`

Comment: Hi karthik, that query will work but if i combine it with another condition its not working...along with the range of date values from date and to date and the date values with due_date=NULL should also display.Please see above with my updated code.

Comment: Can you please help me in rectifying where i am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36461/discussion-between-learner-sfdc-and-karthikselva).